# 'Page' object has no attribute 'ordered' Exception

Tags: python, django, pagination

I need to paginate my modelformset_factory but I am getting this exception:

```
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Page' object has no attribute 'ordered'
```

I have this in my view:

```
BrandFormSet = modelformset_factory(Brand, form=BrandFormList, extra=0, **kw)

paginator, brands = paginate(request, Brand.objects.filter(shop=shop), 10)
```

paginate function code:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def paginate(request, object_list, per_page):
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, per_page)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        objects = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        objects = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        objects = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return paginator, objects
```

Now this in my view:

```
print type(Brand.objects.filter(shop=request.user.shop))
print type(brands)
```

Outputs:

```
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
<class 'django.core.paginator.Page'>
```

I am not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using `brands` (a `Page`) in a context that's expecting a `QuerySet`.

It doesn't seem as though pagination and formsets were designed to work together. From glancing at the source code, it looks like `brands.object_list` might still be a `QuerySet`. If so, use that where you were using `brands` before.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14128835/2395796) gives a hacky solution for using the two together, but it's quite inefficient. (It makes one trip to the database to get the desired item ids, and then constructs a new `QueryList` that explicitly includes those ids.)

Comment: With brands.object_list I got a new error: Exception Value: Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.

Comment: @Adam: Hmm, that strengthens my feeling that these two features were just not designed to work together. I don't have a better idea than the one in the answer I linked to, where he just creates a new queryset from scratch...